# First Child, Next Sibling

Tags: dom

Are the dom core props:

```
.firstChild
.nextSibling
```

supported cross-browser-platforrm-browserVersion?

Comment: don't you trust the official resources?

Comment: also, define cross-browser. It doesn't work in my HTML parser with rudimentary javascript support.

Comment: ... like cross A-list browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html), yes, they are supported everywhere.

Comment: Just pay attention, sometimes "newline" between two adjacent nodes is removed, sometimes it creates an empty text node, so nextSibling may return two different nodes in two different browsers.

Comment: I assume there is a way to test for such a case by creating the 'critical circumstance' and seeing what browser did, storing the result for use else where...